# Can Jupyter Notebook run on Windows 10

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, desktop

I installed Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10. But I got an error when launching it in Visual Studio Code as:

`jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of  the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

After searching online, I decided to install Anaconda first and run Jupyter from it. But launching it from Anaconda was directed to a web address. It looks like Jupyter is only a web application.

I wonder if it is possible to run the Jupyter Notebook as a desktop application on Windows.

Comment: There is also a JupyterLab Desktop App, see [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-app-now-available-b8b661b17e9a) and [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-2022-recap-28bdf00205c6). I don't know how old of a version of Windows works for it.

Comment: Does it work with VS Code?

Comment: Jupyter itself works with VScode to run Jupyter notebooks in VScode. You wouldn't need the JupyterLab Desktop App in that case. You do need Jupyter though. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) if you are interested in using Jupyter notebooks in VSCode.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to reinstall them. It is possible you could add the already installed ones to your path, but if you have room it is easiest to keep your Anaconda installed stuff where it is and separate from what you had. The easiest way to sort where to install them is to let Jupyter handle it. For example, if you want to work with Pandas in a notebook, in that notebook run `%conda install -c anaconda pandas`, based on [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas). For the packages that conda cannot install, and only for those, use `%pip install <package_name>`.

Comment: You can delete the install commands out of the notebook after if you want. You may just want to comment them out so you remember. For the short term you are fine re-running the commands because if the package is already installed by conda or pip it won't get reinstalled; however, if the package gets a new release and you aren't specifying versions, you'll get the latest when that install command next runs and if there is an error or incompatibility, then you'll have caused yourself an issue you could have avoided.

Comment: After changing the python interpreter to anaconda, some old python programs can not run because they are for Python3.10 while anaconda is python3.9. Although packages used point to packages in anaconda. What do you do with this problem?

Comment: Do I have to convert all the python programs to jupyter notebook in order to run?

Comment: No, Jupyter works with scripts. You can either run in the terminal like normal inside Jupyter or run from in the notebook (or IPython console) by using `%run <script_name.py>`. The run magic has additional options such as the `-i` flag to run the script in the current notebook namespace, or in the case of IPython, the console namespace. See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) about the %run IPython magic that also works in Jupyter notebooks. You can also pass arguments in when using `%run` similar to what you'd do if running on the command line.

Comment: As for Python 3.10. You can use that. See mention of a metapackage for that [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/anaconda-distribution-2022-10). What you want to do is create a new environment and install Python 3.10 in that. See the command example [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12951#issuecomment-1362105103). You can replace the name of the environment with what you want to call it. You'll want to look up how to activate the environment using the Anaconda terminal in the documentation.

Comment: Conda failed to install wget. So I installed wget by pip. But when running it in notebook, I got the error: "wget is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". What is the problem?

Comment: Windows doesn't have wget and I don't think pip would be able to install it. If you want wget and other unix stuff you probably want to be working in WSL. Or see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-or-curl), [here](https://www.jcchouinard.com/wget/), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/77247/how-do-i-install-wget-for-windows), [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/wget/?platform=windows), etc..

Comment: What is -c in conda install? Is it necessary?

Comment: After choosing conda (by selecting python interpreter in vs code), the python path (sys.path) has been changed. That is why my previous .py files can not work even if I select python interpreter back to original one. Is it possible to restore the path so that I can run old python extension? Sorry for asking these here because Stackoverflow does not allow me to ask questions in 3 days. I will post these as new posts later so that you can get points.

Comment: That is flag for specifying the channel. It is necessary if the package isn't in the main Anaconda channel (or what your system defaults to or checks). Pandas should work without it but other things that are in conda-forge or the bioconda channel probably wouldn't work without specifying the channel. That's why I linked to the specific command example at Anaconda's site. Always best to search in your search engine 'anaconda' and the package name to get to the place that will give you the exact command to use.

Comment: "Is it possible to restore the path so that I can run old python extension?" Probably is; however, you'd have to search VScode specific stuff. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JupyterLab Desktop App, see [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-app-now-available-b8b661b17e9a) and [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-2022-recap-28bdf00205c6). I don't know how old of a version of Windows works for it.

---

**Rest was built from discussion in comments:**

On Jupyter with VS Code:

Jupyter itself works with VScode to run Jupyter notebooks in VScode. You wouldn't need the JupyterLab Desktop App in that case. You do need Jupyter though. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) if you are interested in using Jupyter notebooks in VSCode.

On installing packages that worked before installed Anaconda:

The easiest solution would be to reinstall them. It is possible you could add the already installed ones to your path, but if you have room it is easiest to keep your Anaconda installed stuff where it is and separate from what you had. The easiest way to sort where to install them is to let Jupyter handle it. For example, if you want to work with Pandas in a notebook, in that notebook run `%conda install -c anaconda pandas`, based on [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas) and [the magic install command](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). For the packages that conda cannot install, and only for those, use `%pip install <package_name>`.

You can delete the install commands out of the notebook after if you want. You may just want to comment them out so you remember. For the short term you are fine re-running the commands because if the package is already installed by conda or pip it won't get reinstalled; however, if the package gets a new release and you aren't specifying versions, you'll get the latest when that install command next runs and if there is an error or incompatibility, then you'll have caused yourself an issue you could have avoided.